# 僕は死んだら vs 僕は死んでも

Tags: words, grammar

I was watching an anime and after B sold all his books and gave the money to A so that he could pay rent, A said:

- 僕は死んだらあなたを守りますよ。

which was translated as "Even if I die, I'll protect you".
But I think that while 「僕が死んでもあなたを守りますよ」would mean "Even if I die, I'll protect you", 「僕は死んだらあなたを守りますよ」means "When I die, I'll protect you".

Is that correct? If not, I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: You're correct in that も makes it an explicit "even", which is lacking in the original version. However, I feel that, given the actual meaning of the phrase, translating it without the word "even" would sound pretty wrong in English (too "matter of fact" for such an emphatic statement).

Comment: It could be "When I die, I'll protect you", as たら can express a condition or time when the action happens. Actually, I think this translation would be more accurate. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

1.「僕は死んだらあなたを守りますよ。」is semantically bit difficult to understand. The literal translation should be "When/If I die, I'll protect you". Probably A would like to say they will protect B as a guardian angel even if they will not exist within this world since A is very thankful to B because of B's selfless attitude.

2.「僕が死んでもあなたを守りますよ」would mean "I'll protect you with my life" or "I will risk my own life to protect you". So, if something happens to B, A is probably ready to throw their life away for B.

All in all, the 1st one sounds more spiritual sense, the 2nd one sounds more physical sense. But since I have not watched the anime, it's very speculative.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. I also feel the same question and expect what will A do after his death.